# Pass $this to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

How can I pass the $this (the self keyword) to a function in Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.nav a').click(function() {
        var direction = $(this).attr("name");
        submit_form($(this))
    }); 

    function submit_form(this)
    {
        // do some stuff with 'this'
    }       
});
```

Comment: You already do it correctly. Just rename the variable in `function submit_form(this){}` to something else like `function submit_form(element){}`.

Comment: Please use javascript the way it was intended to be used (no need to pass context as a parameter): `submit_form.call(this)`, `submit_form.apply(this)`, or even use jQuery if that's the only thing you understand: `jQuery.proxy(submit_form, this)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wrapping it in `$()` makes it a jQuery object. You would want to do something like

```
submit_form(this);

function submit_form(obj)
{
    // Work with `obj` as "this"
    // Or wrap it in $() to work with it as jQuery(this)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `this` keyword cannot be set in JavaScript. It is automatically generated by JavaScript and "always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of".
— http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

You have one problem in your code (trying to name the parameter of the submit_form() function to this). However, the way your code is laid out doesn't make it clear whether you're intending to pass along the clicked anchor wrapped as a jQuery object or as the DOM node for the anchor.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav a').click(function() {
        $anchor = $(this);                      // Capture the jQuery-wrapped anchor for re-use; 'this' is an anchor because it matched $('.nav a')
        var direction = $anchor.attr("name");   // $variable_name is a standard pattern in jQuery to indicate variables that are jQuery-wrapped instead of DOM objects

        submit_form_jquery($anchor);            // Providing versions of submit_form function for passing either jQuery-wrapped object or DOM object
        submit_form_dom(this);                  // Pick the one you prefer and use it
    }); 

    function submit_form_jquery($my_anchor) {   // Function with well-named parameter expecting a jQuery-wrapped object
        // do some stuff with '$my_anchor'
        // $my_anchor here is assumed to be a jQuery-wrapped object
    }

    function submit_form_dom(anchor) {          // Function named expecting a DOM element, not a jQuery-wrapped element
        // do some stuff with 'anchor'
        // anchor here is assumed to be a DOM element, NOT wrapped in a jQuery object
    }
});
```

On a mostly unrelated note, you'll probably want to either `return false;` or use event.preventDefault() to keep the page from following the `href` on the anchor that was clicked. You can do that as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // And now do what you want the click to do
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $('.nav a').click(function()    { 
            var direction = $(this).attr("name"); 
            submit_form(this);
        });  

        function submit_form(myObject) 
        { 
            // do some stuff with 'myObject'


        }        

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.nav a').click(function()    {
        submit_form(this)
    }); 

    function submit_form(thisObject)
    {
        var direction = $(thisObject).attr("name");
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *this* can be set easily. See `Function.call()` and `Function.apply()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it as a normal variable?

```
function submit_form(context)
{
    context.html("Boo!");

}

/// Then when you call it:
submit_form($(this));
```